# Unity 2D - HP bar

Tags: unity-game-engine

The value of my HP bar drops when my runner collides an obstacle. Of course, Value of HP drop nomally, but Image of HP bar does not change. Why do I get an error?

```cs
public class CsRunner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 jumpVelocity;
    public float _hp = 100f;
    public float _curHP;
    bool isJump;
    public Image _hpValue;

    bool collision_box;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        _hpValue = GameObject.Find("HPbar").GetComponent<Image>();
        _curHP = _hp;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        _hpValue.fillAmount = _curHP / _hp;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isJump)
        {
            isJump = false;
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpVelocity/2, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if ((Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && collision_box)
        {
            isJump = true;
            transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(jumpVelocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        else
        {
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Run");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.transform.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            _curHP--;
            _hpValue.fillAmount = _curHP / _hp;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my scene :

[image]

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: What is your settings of HPbar? Please select it,take screenshot and put it in your question.

Comment: @Programmer OK. I add it:)

Comment: You code looks fine and the Image settings is ok. You said you are getting an error....What is the error?

Comment: seems like your "fillAmount = 1.0f". the problem what could be is that u are deviding you health/100, so u have 0.009f, what probably wont be noticable. Try to update fill.Amount with higher values.

Comment: @Programmer Hp bar doesn't move. Even My runner collides Obstacle.

Comment: @Demon You mean setting maxHealth higher value? Example 1000?

Comment: (OFFTOPIC)Just as a side note, it would be more effective (as of performance) if you store your Rigidbody2D in a member variable, instead of GetComponent() every time in Update()

Comment: @Diana try to change  _hpValue.fillAmount = _curHP / _hp to _hpValue.fillAmount = _curHP this;

Comment: @Mark Store Rigidbody2D variable? Can you upload example?

Comment: private Rigidbody myRB; and in Start() or Awake() myRB = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); From Update(), you can myRB.AddForce. Basically, the same thing you do with your "_hpValue"

Comment: @Demon Including 'this'? _hpValue.fillAmount = _curHP this;, right? but It cause syntax error.

Comment: Oh, I fixed error... I typeded code GameObject.Find('HPbar'), but GameObject.Find('HP'). Thanks to everyone!!

Comment: Didn't even notice that from the first Image. It says HP not HPbar. Congrats on the fix.

Comment: @Programmer Oh, I see. Thanks for the advice:D

Comment: You are welcome. Happy coding!